# When assigning hardcoded string to variable pytumblr works, but when dynamically passed it does not work

Tags: python, pytumblr

I am trying to save a post to tumblr queue from image links.

```
line = "https://68.media.tumblr.com/b965fbb2e501610a29d80ffb6fb3e1ad/tumblr_n55vdeTse11rn1906o1_500.jpg"
client.create_photo(blogName, state="queue", tags=["testing", "ok"],
                    source=line)
print(line)
```

Output is

```
https://68.media.tumblr.com/b965fbb2e501610a29d80ffb6fb3e1ad/tumblr_n55vdeTse11rn1906o1_500.jpg
```

The post is **successfully added** to the queue as desired.

However, I have a file with a list of image urls and I am reading and looping into them by using readlines().

```
for line in lines:
    client.create_photo(blogName, state="queue", tags=["testing", "ok"],
                    source=line)
    print(line)
    exit()
```

Output is same as above

```
https://68.media.tumblr.com/b965fbb2e501610a29d80ffb6fb3e1ad/tumblr_n55vdeTse11rn1906o1_500.jpg
```

However, the post is not actually created in the queue and also no exception is thrown.

I am unable to figure out what's wrong.

I have the same problem when trying to upload using local files as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `line.strip()` instead of `line` to that function.

The `readlines()` method returns list of strings ending with `"\n"` symbol which needs to be stripped, so actually it would be better to read lines from file this way:

```
lines = [l.strip() for l in file.readlines if l.strip()]
```

This way you're ignoring `"\n"`s and empty lines.